Render Without Being Affected by Light
so i wanted to make a png rotate in a 3dimensional axis, i haveimported an image as a plane and keyframed the rotation, but everytime i tried to render in blender, the png color always got off due to the lighting, is theres a way to render a png that i import, without being affected by light so the hex code remain the same, and remain transparent? probably like Adobe After Effect
is there is a compositing trick or render setting that could help? I prefer eevee.
I have find an answer but this require me to use cycles, by rendering diffuse color channel and opening compositor, put diffcol to image socket in "set alpha" node and put alpha to alpha socket it "set alpha" node.

Simply take an Emission shader, plug the Image Texture into the Color. Take a Mix Shader, plug a Transparent BSDF into the first input, the Emission in the second and use the Alpha channel of the image as mix factor. Works in Cycles immediately and in EEVEE if you set the transparency settings correctly.

I have found a trick by setting my cycles render pass to a very low number and it renders quickly now!
heres the setup




The trick with the Diffuse Color output in the compositor like you've shown in your comment should work exactly the same for Eevee as it does for Cycles.
It's worth noting that if you want exactly the same color in the output render, you will need to additionally change the View Transform in the color management:

Blender normally shifts the output colors to color spaces useful for higher dynamic range or cinematic applications, but if you want exactly the same colors out as you put in, "Standard" is your View Transform of choice.
